# Graceful way to check if a PETSc vector/matrix has been destroyed?

Tags: vector, matrix, petsc

For a unit test, I'm trying to make sure that a PETSc vector has been destroy.  However, I can't seem to find an adequate command that does this gracefully.  The best I've been able to do is call VecSetType(...) and look at the error.  However, this write PETSC_ERROR output, that I do not want to be written, particularly since I'm expecting an error.  Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an experienced PetSc user but I know that XDestroy functions are equating the Vec, Mat etc. to NULL. I guess you may compare your VEC with NULL. For me, I'm using a finalizer class to make sure that everything is cleaned up properly. Hope works

Answer (score 0):

you can run the code with -log_summary. The profiling information constitute a table for how many vectors have been created and how many of them have been destroyed.